# Linux drivers for Richland Radeon HD 8550G graphics?

Tags: linux, laptop, drivers, graphics-card, xorg

I am attempting to configure the graphics drivers in Debian for my HP Envy 15z-j100 laptop, which has a Richland [Radeon HD 8550G] graphics card.

The graphics work with the default installation, but I have some issues with controlling the screen brightness[1](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTI5Mjka).  I am unsure what "stack" the default installation is running.  This [Phoronix Article](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTI5Mjka) among others seems to indicate that there are open source drivers for the 8550, but I'm not sure how to tell if I'm using the "proper" open source driver or just the generic one. glxinfo lists "Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe", and says direct rendering is enabled, which is ambiguous to me.  The gnome-control-center system "details" says that I'm using "VESA: DVST" with a "fallback" experience, which to me indicates that the proper drivers are not being used.

I have tried looking for information about using the 8000 line cards on Linux, but to no avail.  For example [Xorg's list of supported RadeonHD cards](http://xorg.freedesktop.org/wiki/radeonhd:feature/) doesn't mention the 8000 line.  Is there an accelerated open source driver?  How can I tell if I'm using it?

I also tried installing the non-free fglrx-driver package, and I found that the screen brightness began working, but there were some issues with flicker and video tearing (the brightness briefly flickers to maximum every time it is adjusted, for example).

[1](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTI5Mjka):  While the brightness keys appear to work, the brightness bar that pops up is stuck at the maximum/next to maximum setting, and switching between them causes no change in the actual brightness of the screen.  Furthermore, changing the values in /sys/class/backlight/... has no effect.  I have tried a wide variety of kernel settings to try to fix this, but none of the suggestions I found online worked.

Comment: I am not entirely familiar with Linux to the level.  I can tell you even on Windows devices the display brightness is handled by the monitor's driver not the display driver ( i.e. the dGPU or iGPU) device.

Comment: I found this page which is the first I have found to classify the Radeon HD8550M (not G like my card), and apparently it's the "oland" chipset in the "southern islands" family.